# Зачем использовать синглтон в статическом классе, если можно создать один экземпляр обычного класса

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Не понимаю, зачем использовать синглтон в статическом классе, если можно создать один экземпляр обычного класса ?

**Вместо этого:**

```
class SingletonTest {

protected static $_instance;

private function __construct() {

}

private function __clone() {

}
public static function getInstance() {
    // проверяем актуальность экземпляра
    if (null === self::$_instance) {
        // создаем новый экземпляр
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    // возвращаем созданный или существующий экземпляр
    return self::$_instance;
}
}
```

**Это**

```
class Test {

   function __construct() {

   }

}

$test = new Test();
```

Comment: Вы дошли до очень простой истины: синглтон не нужен вообще в принципе, нигде и никогда и является антипаттерном.

Comment: @Etki Обоснуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @kff синглтон не тестируется например через юнит тесты

Comment: @kff пойдем от обратного - где он нужен?

Comment: Ну как я понял, он нужен в крупных проектах, чтобы кто-то не знающий полностью архитектуры проекта, не смог создать ещё один экземпляр класса

Comment: @Accami да нет, он вообще в принципе не нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синглтон контролирует число созданных экземпляров класса и не позволяет программисту по ошибке создать более одного. Ручное создание лишено контроля и в программе случайно может появиться несколько экземпляров класса, что может быть фатальной и трудноопределяемой ошибкой.

Если программка маленькая, а вы ***абсолютно*** уверены в своих действиях, то можно обойтись и без синглтона. Но если вы работаете в команде над большими проектами, то синглтон будет просто необходим.

---

**UPDATE**

Может возникнуть также вопрос, почему синглтон хранится в *статической* переменной. Дело в том, что синглтон запрещает внешнему коду явное создание экземпляров класса, поэтому для получения экземпляра нужно использовать *статический метод*. А статический метод имеет доступ только к статическим переменным.

Comment: Спасибо, еще вопрос, почему синглтон всегда реализуется при помощи статического класса ?

Comment: @AndreyPopov Не такого понятия как "статический класс".